# Trying to draw a model with Gouraud shading in jogl for desktop, but is flat

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I already have a drawn model, but it has flat shading (for what I understand it should be smooth by default...)

This is the initial config:

```
private void SetLightningAndMaterials(){
    //float[] lightPos = {1, 1, 1, 0};
    float[] lightPos = {0, 0, 1, 0};
    float[] lightColorDiffuse = {1, 1, 1, 1};    
    float[] lightColorAmbient = {0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1};     

    gl.glShadeModel(GL.GL_SMOOTH); 

    gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT1, GL.GL_POSITION, lightPos, 0);
    gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT1, GL.GL_DIFFUSE, lightColorDiffuse, 0);
    gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT1, GL.GL_AMBIENT, lightColorAmbient, 0);        

    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHT1);
    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHTING);

    gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_AMBIENT, ambientColour, 0);   
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_DIFFUSE, mesh.colour, 0);

    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHTING);   
    gl.glEnable(GL.GL_LIGHT0);
    float[] noAmbient =
    { 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1f }; // low ambient light
    float[] spec =
    { 1f, 0.6f, 0f, 1f }; // low ambient light
    float[] diffuse =
    { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1f };
    gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_AMBIENT, noAmbient, 0);  
    gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_SPECULAR, spec, 0);  
    gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse, 0);  
    gl.glLightfv(GL.GL_LIGHT0, GL.GL_POSITION, new float[]{0,0,10,1}, 0);
}
```

And this is how I draw the model:

```
public void Draw(GL gl, GLU glu){      
Vec3d normal;
MassPoint vertex1, vertex2, vertex3;
int faceIndex=0;
Face surfaceFace;

for (faceIndex=0; faceIndex<surfaceFaces.size();faceIndex++){
    surfaceFace = surfaceFaces.get(faceIndex);
    surfaceFace.recalculateNormal();
    vertex1 = surfaceFace.vertex1;            
    vertex2 = surfaceFace.vertex2;            
    vertex3 = surfaceFace.vertex3;
    normal = surfaceFace.normal;   

    gl.glBegin(gl.GL_TRIANGLES); 
        gl.glNormal3d(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);  

        gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_DIFFUSE, colour, 0);
        gl.glVertex3d(vertex1.position.x, vertex1.position.y, vertex1.position.z);  

        gl.glVertex3d(vertex2.position.x, vertex2.position.y, vertex2.position.z);

        gl.glVertex3d(vertex3.position.x, vertex3.position.y, vertex3.position.z);

    gl.glEnd();               
}   
}
```

I want to believe there's an easy way of solving this without having to create a shader (I don't have any idea how to set these in Java).
I'm using JOGL 1 by the way, and is probably an old version (the imports are like javax.media.opengl.*).

Comment: Don't waste your time on [deprecated OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL), you should start learning current opengl, I ported to jogl one very good tutorial [here](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples)

Comment: Please switch to JOGL 2. We stopped maintaining JOGL 1 at least 6 years ago, using obsolete piece of software is a bad idea. By the way, I advise you to look at our examples, some contributors ported the examples of the OpenGL Red Book, look at jogl-demos on Github, this example demonstrates how to use GL_SMOOTH: https://github.com/JogAmp/jogl-demos/blob/master/src/redbook/src/glredbook10/light.java

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. For smoothness to work, the drawing expects 3 normals (one per vertex), I was only passing 1 normal (one per face).

Here's the new code for the drawing:

```
public void Draw(GL gl, GLU glu) {      
    Vec3d[] normalsPerVertex = new Vec3d[3];
    MassPoint vertex1, vertex2, vertex3;

    int faceIndex=0;
    Face surfaceFace;
    for (faceIndex=0; faceIndex<surfaceFaces.size();faceIndex++){
        surfaceFace = surfaceFaces.get(faceIndex);
            vertex1=surfaceFace.vertex1;   
            normalsPerVertex[0] = vertex1.CalcNormal();
            vertex2=surfaceFace.vertex2;   
            normalsPerVertex[1] = vertex2.CalcNormal();         
            vertex3=surfaceFace.vertex3;
            normalsPerVertex[2] = vertex3.CalcNormal();

            gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);  
                gl.glNormal3d(normalsPerVertex[0].x, normalsPerVertex[0].y, normalsPerVertex[0].z);  
                gl.glVertex3d(vertex1.position.x, vertex1.position.y, vertex1.position.z);  

                gl.glNormal3d(normalsPerVertex[1].x, normalsPerVertex[1].y, normalsPerVertex[1].z);  
                gl.glVertex3d(vertex2.position.x, vertex2.position.y, vertex2.position.z);

                gl.glNormal3d(normalsPerVertex[2].x, normalsPerVertex[2].y, normalsPerVertex[2].z);  
                gl.glVertex3d(vertex3.position.x, vertex3.position.y, vertex3.position.z);

            gl.glEnd();  
    }   
}
```

The calculated normal for each vertex is the media of all the faces connected to that vertex. Here's the code for that:

```
public Vec3d CalcNormal() {
    Vec3d normalMedia = new Vec3d();
    for (Face face : facesRelated) {
        face.recalculateNormal();
        normalMedia.add(face.normal);
    }
    normalMedia.mul(1d/facesRelated.size());
    return normalMedia;
}
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: GL_TRIANGLES is a static field, there is no need to use an instance. Please port your code to JOGL 2 to avoid causing any confusion as JOGL 1 is obsolete and no longer maintained.

Comment: Updated the static field part. About the JOGL 2 thing, it's a finished old project, I don't need to update it. Please consider my answer as a useful one.

Comment: Yes they are useful and I can edit your code here to use JOGL 2 if you want. I mustn't upvote a content using an obsolete version of JOGL whereas your answer deserves an upvote as it's correct. Where does Vec3 come from?